# How often put() is triggered in Kafka Connect sink tasks?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Can I control the intervals at which the `put()` method of my Kafka Connect Sink tasks is triggered? What is the expected behavior of the Kafka Connect framework in this respect? Ideally, I would like to specify, for example, "don't call me unless you have X new records/Y new bytes, or Z milliseconds passed since the last invocation". This could potentially make the batching logic within the sink task simpler (quoting the [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_sinktasks), "*in many cases internal buffering will be useful so an entire batch of records can be sent at once, reducing the overhead of inserting events into the downstream data store*).

Answer (score 1):

Today, put from a `SinkTask` is only called when [deliverMessages](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java#L384) is invoked in a `WorkerSinkTask`.  The good news is that the only time `deliverMessages` happens is within [poll](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java#L213) so you should have some control over how often you poll for new records by  [overriding consumer properties](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/userguide.html#overriding-producer-consumer-settings).

If you want to do internal buffering, you could have a look at how the HDFSConnector is handling this in its [implementation of SinkTask](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/hdfs/HdfsSinkTask.java#L101).  However, right now, Connect will immediately put any records that get returned by the poll.

All of that said, if you are really looking to batch messages before they hit the downstream system, you might consider looking into [offset.flush.interval.ms and offset.flush.timeout.ms](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/userguide.html#common-worker-configs) which control how often `flush()` is invoked.